# Spring Boot jpa specification for one to many relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot JPA specification for applying different filters. I have a table structure like below,

```
Parent Table:

| parent_id | parent_name |
| --------- | ----------- |
| 11        | parent      |

Child1 Table:

| child1_id | child1_name | child1_parent_id | child1_another_parent_id |
| --------  | ----------  | ---------------- | ------------------------ |
| 22        | child1_1    | 11               | 777                      |
| 33        | child1_2    | 11               | 888                      |   

Child2 Table:

| child2_id | child2_name | child2_parent_id | child2_another_parent_id |
| --------  | ----------  | ---------------  | ------------------------ |
| 44        | child2_1    | 11               | 777                      |
| 55        | child2_2    | 11               | 888                      |
```

Now, if I pass the filter criteria as parent_id = 11 and another_parent_id=777, I should get 2 records. I have formed query like below.

Query -

```
select * from parent 
left outer join child1 on child1_parent_id = parent_id 
left outer join child2 on child2_parent_id = parent_id 
where parent_id=11 and
(child1_another_col_id=777) or (child2_another_col_id=77)
```

Result -

```
 | parent_id | parent_name | child1_id | child1_name | child1_parent_id | child1_another_parent_id | child2_id | child2_name | child2_parent_id | child2_another_col_id |
    11       | parent      | 22        | child1_1    | 11               | 777                 | NULL                   | NULL        | NULL      | NULL

    11       | parent      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL             | NULL                | 44        | child2_1    | 11        | 777
```

Now if I convert the same to specification,

```
Parent Repository-
          final var predicates = new ArrayList<>();
          Join<Parent, Child1> joinChild1 = root.join("child1List", JoinType.LEFT);
          Join<Child1, AnotherParent> joinAnotherParent1 = joinChild1 .join("anotherParent", JoinType.LEFT);
    
          Join<Parent, Child2> joinChild2 = root.join("child2List", JoinType.LEFT);
          Join<Child1, AnotherParent> joinAnotherParent2 = joinChild2 .join("anotherParent", JoinType.LEFT);

          predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(joinAnotherParent1 .get("id"), 777));   
          predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(joinAnotherParent2 .get("id"), 777));
 
          criteriaBuilder.or(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
          criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("parentId", 11)));
```

With above code I get right query getting formed and also I get the Parent record which is of Id 11. But when I traverse to child1 (parent.getChild1()) and child2 (parent.getChild2()), I get both the records of child1 and child2 each. Where I am expecting only 1 record each child based on another_col_id=777.

Should I need to create separate repositories for child1 and child2 and add the specification individually? In that case it will hit DB twice with create 2 queries, one for child1 and once for child2. What is the right approach?